# Question regarding Visible=false and display:none;

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

If I set some control's property Visible="false", I cant see the control in the HTML generated of my aspx page. But when I use display:none in style tag for that control, I see the control as greyed out in the HTML. Why is that?

Also, If I find some control that is not needed on the page anymore:-

1. should I comment it out from my page?
2. Should I set its property Visible=false"
3. Should I set display:none?

What would be the best approach keeping in mind the time constraint and page's heaviness?

Below is the HTML that was generated of my test page:-

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title> </title>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" action="testvisibility.aspx" method="post" name="form1">
<div>
<input id="__VIEWSTATE" type="hidden" value="/wEPDwUKMTY2NDk3NDQzNQ9kFgICAw9kFgQCBw8PFgIeB1Zpc2libGVoZGQCCQ8WAh4Fc3R5bGUFDWRpc3BsYXk6bm9uZTtkZEjYzMWMovvrGmuSrQHwc5ZXgqXCrf+lekz1GgsdjUd+" name="__VIEWSTATE">
</div>
<div>
visiblelabel::
<span id="visiblelabel">visiblelabel</span>
<br>
labelwithvisiblefalseonaspx::
<br>
labelwithdisplaynoneonaspx::
<div style="display: none;">
<span id="labelwithdisplaynoneonaspx">labelwithdisplaynoneonaspx</span>
</div>
<br>
labelwithvisiblefalseonserverside::
<br>
labelwithdisplaynoneonserverside::
<div id="divforlabelwithdisplaynoneonserverside" style="display: none;">
<span id="labelwithdisplaynoneonserverside">labelwithdisplaynoneonserverside</span>
</div>
<br>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to dynamically show or hide the control via Ajax/etc, or if the control contains information your page needs, set `display:none` in CSS.

If you don't want to render the control at all *in certain situations*, set `Visible="false"`.  Since it keeps the control's HTML out of the page, it makes for slightly smaller pages -- but if you want to show the control via Ajax/etc, this won't work.

If you don't want to render the control at all, *period*, don't comment it out -- remove it altogether.  All controls, visible or not, still require processing, so Visible=false is wasting CPU (and possibly causing side effects) if you never intend to render the control.  And you really don't want lots of commented-out stuff floating around; it just makes maintenance harder.  You can always get it back from your revision control if you find you do need it later.  (You *are* using SVN/Git/CVS/*something*, right?)

Answer (score 5):

The `Visible` property is a property on the control - when set to false the control doesn't render at all. This is much better then setting `display:none`, in which case the control is rendered with a `display:none` style, so that the browser won't display it.

The `display:none` can be useful if you don't want the control to be visible, but it contains some data that you want to use on the client (through Javascript, say). In such a case setting the `Visible` property to false won't work.

Comment: Thank you @Petar, yes in case we want to manipulate the content via Javascript then we should use `display>none` otherwise it **won't work**

Answer (score 2):

I can't say which one is better, it's depend on situation. If you want to use that control in client site (i.e. wants to access the control by JavaScript) , you have to set the display to none. But if you don't need it in client-side its better to set the visible to false.

Answer (score 1):

I think the important difference lies in whether you need access to the items inside the panels, client-side.  Setting visible=false will cause the panel not to be rendered, so you can't get at any of the controls, once again, client-side.  Whereas if you set display none, then you will have access to the controls, as the panel is rendered.one more concern about visible=false avoid validation.