# Invisible DIV not available to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Im sure the answer to my question is here somewhere but I cannot find it.  I apologise if I have duplicated.

I have a DIV that I set its visiblity on page load depending on the data I pull back.

So in the code behind:

`this.divMyDiv.Visible = false`

If the user then changes a drop down value I try to show the DIV

```
var div = document.getElementById('divMyDiv');
div.style.display = 'block';
```

If the div is set to visible by the code behind on the initial page load all is fine.  The DIV will show and hide when I change the drop down value.  However when the DIV is hidden on page load the var div in the JavaScript is always null.  I have tried `var div = document.getElementById('<%=divMyDiv.ClientID%>');` but I get the same results.  I have also tried moving the JS to the bottom of the page.  Same results.

Comment: Wish I could mark more than one as an answer.  Marked the one I ran with.  Thanks all.

Comment: @downvoter  Be nice if you could leave a comment so I know where I went wrong with this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
this.divMyDiv.Visible = false
```

...will prevent the div from being rendered at all and Javascript can't find it. If you still want to render it and use `display:none` to hide it, you'll want to do;

```
this.divMyDiv.Style["display"] = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting an aspx control to `Visible = false` on the server side means that the control won't be rendered at all in the Html Response, and thus it isn't available at all client-side for javascript to use. You'll need to render it (`Visible=true`) but then Hide the control using css, e.g. `style='display:none'` or similar. See also [Question regarding Visible=false and display:none;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6907422/question-regarding-visible-false-and-displaynone)

Answer (score 0):

If this property is false, the server control is not rendered. You should take this into account when organizing the layout of your page.

If you want the control to be rendered but not visible, you should leave Visble = true and hide the control using script or css.

```
div.style.display = 'none';
```

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.visible.aspx

Answer (score 0):

in code behind use

instead of 
     this.divMyDiv.Visible = false
use this
     divMyDivAttributes.Add("display", "none");

It will then be rendered by javascript and your other java script function will run properly too