# Can't retrieve invisible elements with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, datatable, getelementbyid

Am working on a data table, that is based on this api http://www.datatables.net/examples/api/multi_filter_select.html
I have done some modification, but the main idea is the same.

At the moment i want to make it possible for the user to click on a row which makes it selected and changes color. If the user clicks on another row the old one gets unselected and color get changed back. But as you can see in the API example you can minimize the visual result by searching or change the amount of entries that should be visible.

The code for selecting and deselecting is below:

```
unction select(t) {
imei=t;
//console.log("IMEI");
//console.log(imei);

if(selected!=""){
    console.log("Selected"+selected);

    document.getElementById(selected).style.backgroundColor=savedColor;
}
selected= t;
savedColor=document.getElementById(selected).style.backgroundColor;
document.getElementById(selected).style.backgroundColor='#F7F000';
```

}

The problem is that when a user selects a row and then make a search which make the selected item invisible and then selects a new row. Then when i want to retrieve the old row by document.getElementById(selected) so i can change the color to the old one, it return null.

It's only when the element is not visible. If the previous is visible when selecting a new one, it works-

Comment: possible duplicate of [Invisible DIV not available to JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667411/invisible-div-not-available-to-javascript)

Comment: Am pretty new to javascript and i cant find any Visible = false in the javascript code, i can't track the code where the vissibliity code is executed

Comment: I assume this is being done in the code behind. Read the other question and answers carefully.